# AsyncHttpClient sets content-type inconsistently

Tags: java, http, http-headers, asynchttpclient

I use AsyncHttpClient to create an http POST request:

```
      AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder reqBuilder;
      reqBuilder = httpClient.preparePost(url);
      reqBuilder.setBody(data);
```

It sometimes doesn't send content-type header and sometimes sends it as

```
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

which causes our request to fail at [REST API] server side.

I am at a loss to understand why it is inconsistent.

Client is created as below:

```
      import com.ning.http.client.*;
       AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(
         new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().build());
```

Comment: Why only post short excerpt? Please post more code. E.g. what is `httpClient`? It would be interesting to see how it was created.

Comment: @bpgergo - done - see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can set headers by your self

```
reqBuilder.setHeader(String name, String value);
```

or add

```
reqBuilder.addHeader(String name, String value);
```

Comment: AHC doesn't set the Content-Type automatically for you. You indeed have to set it explicitly yourself on the RequestBuilder.